# CodeKit 2.0.2: Sass source maps not working

Tags: css, sass, source-maps, codekit

I’ve been trying to enable this for the better part of the last few hours…

I enabled the source maps in the project settings in CodeKit.

However, no CSS source map is being generated. I’ve checked the Chrome settings, the source maps option is enabled, as well as the individual switches for CSS and JS under Sources, but it still doesn’t work.

Does anybody know how to activate this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a Compass project?

Comment: Yes, a Compass project created in CodeKit.

Answer (score 1):

Source maps aren't currently supported for Compass projects, but will be soon. I'm waiting on the actual release of Compass 1.0.0 (we're still on a pre-release version)

Answer (score 0):

I'm researching the same problem. When I make a dummy set of files new on my desktop, Sourcemaps work fine. When I pull a repository from stash/github it will not generate source maps. So I believe it's a folder permissions error